# Lua - Table.hasValue returning nil

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table something like this:

```
table = {milk, butter, cheese} -- without "Quotation marks"
```

I was searching for a way to check if a given value is in the table or not, and found this:

```
if table.hasValue(table, milk) == true then ...
```

but it returns `nil`, any reason why? (it says `.hasValue` is invalid) or can I get an alternative to check if value exists in that table? I tried several ways like:

```
if table.milk == true then ...
if table[milk] == true then ...
```

All of these returns nil or false.

Comment: have you read the 'programming in lua' book or looked up in the [reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/)? It'd answer all your questions automatically. What gives you the reason to think that there's such a function `hasValue`? What is `milk`, without the quotation marks by the way? As lua is a dynamic language, no one should be too eager to answer a question fully, where many things are not defined.

Comment: The global `table` is a standard library. It's best to treat such globals as reserved variables. Once you run `table =`, you'll no longer have access to the `table` standard library. That's why @Aedil has used [items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24852688/2226988).

Comment: Well @Dimitry I'm sorry I just asked because Google showed up hasValue in several searches. And thanks a lot guys its really appreciated.

Comment: @user3762712 A table only has key-value pairs that you put in it. Try `for key, value in pairs(math) do print(string.format("(%s)%q ⇒ (%s)%q", type(key), tostring(key), type(value), tostring(value))) end` on whatever table you're interested. That was for the math library's table.

Comment: @TomBlodget an i get more details about how can i use `k, v` structure to my table? Like, i already tried it once, it returns fail even with those entries which are fed in table.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov has given you the two best references. They are great for beginners, too (except skip over the C API in the manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
items = {milk=true, butter=true, cheese=true}


if items.milk then
  ...
end
```

OR

```
if items.butter == true then
  ...
end
```

[image]

Comment: In that pic, i accidentally wrote `value = Ryan` actually value is `Milk`

Comment: @user3762712 `tbl.value` indexes `tbl` by _the string `"value"`, not by the contents of the `value` var_. You need `tbl[value]` for that.

Comment: @Aedil actually, it returned `false` even with the value that is inside table. So that means it didnt helped me yet.

Comment: @user3762712 please see the image attached, am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A Lua table can act as an array or as an associative array (map).

There is no hasValue, but by using a table as an associative array you can easily implement it efficiently:

```
local table = {
   milk = true,
   butter = true,
   cheese = true,
}

-- has milk?
if table.milk then
   print("Has milk!")
end

if table.rocks then
   print("Has rocks!")
end
```

Comment: In that pic, i accidentally wrote `value = Ryan` actually value is `Milk`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here.

One, is to create a set:

```
local set = {
 foo  = true,
 bar = true,
 baz = true
}
```

Then you check if either of these are in the table:

```
if set.bar then
```

The drawback to this approach is that you won't iterate over it in any specific order (`pairs` returns items in an arbitrary order).

Another option would be to use a function to check each value in a table. This'll be very slow in large tables, which brings us to back to a modification of the first option: A reverse lookup generator: (This is what I'd recommend doing -- unless your set is static)

```
local data = {"milk", "butter", "cheese"}

local function reverse(tbl, target)
 local target = target or {}

 for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
  target[v] = k
 end

 return target
end

local revdata = reverse(data)

print(revdata.cheese, revdata.butter, revdata.milk)
-- Output: 3    2    1
```

This'll generate a set (with the added bonus of giving you the index where the value was in your original table). You can also put the reverse into the same table as the data was in, but this won't go well with numbers (and it'll be messy if you need to generate the reverse again).

Answer (score 0):

If you write `table = {milk=true, butter=true, cheese=true}`, then you can use `if table.milk == true then ...`.

Comment: In that pic, i accidentally wrote `value = Ryan` actually value is `Milk`